# rails server fails to start with mysql2 using rvm & ruby 1.9.2-p0 on OSX 10.6.5

Tags: macos, rvm, mysql2

I'm getting the following error when I start rails server:

```
$ rails server
/Users/ssmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2.rb:7:in `require':     dlopen(/Users/ssmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib (LoadError) 
Referenced from: /Users/ssmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/mysql2- 0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Users/ssmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/mysql2-    
0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

I've installed mysql2 with the following command after the rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p0 command:

```
$ gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.2.6
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql2-0.2.6...
Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Client not known
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql2-0.2.6...
Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Client not known
```

I have mysql2 in my Gemfile as well as in the database.yml file and bundle install completes fine

```
$ bundle show mysql2
/Users/ssmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/mysql2-0.2.6
```

I understand the rails server error is due to it not knowing the mysql_config location on OSX, however on gem install I specified the correct location.  Yet RVM's gem is not respecting that mysql_config location it seems.

Anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 64):

The problem comes from the mysql2 gem missing the dynamic library from MySQL.

A cleaner solution than `install_name_tool ...` would need to update your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to add MySQL libs to it. To do so, update your `~/.bash_profile` to add the MySQL library folder :

`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"`

Note: You might want to update the MySQL location based on your install

This should keep things clean but also ensure that any gem or code requiring MySQL dynamic libraries will find them.

Reference : http://lightyearsoftware.com/2011/02/mysql-5-5-on-mac-os-x/

**Reference Update July 2012:** A change in OS X 10.8 makes the easy method above less elegant. If you set that variable, every time you run a setuid or setgid program, you get this warning on stderr:

```
dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (...) is setuid or setgid
```

Ruby developers using Phusion Passenger Standalone will see this message displayed in their console every five seconds. It gets really irritating, very fast.

I have filed a bug with Apple. It’s also at OpenRadar.

In the meantime, there is also a third way to fix the client library path problem that doesn’t require setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH (working around this 10.8 issue) or hacking .bundle files with install_name_tool:

```
$ brew install mysql
```

Comment: This won't work if you're using pow or passenger, use Frederic's answer above to get it to work ... make sure to run it on the 'ext' folder in the gem basedir as well

Comment: Also try uninstalling and then reinstalling the mysql2 gem after doing this if you still get the same error. worked for me

Answer (score 22):

I found the answer here: [Mysql 5.5, Snow leopard and rails](http://freddyandersen.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/mysql-5-5-snow-leopard-and-rails/)

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.16.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that every time you (re)install the gem (one example: in a different RVM gemset), you will have to repeat the `install_name_tool` command. Sébastien's answer, which references my blog post, offers a cleaner solution, in my opinion.

Comment: Note that the library version will also change – presently it's libmysqlclient.18.dylib (rather than 16), which needs to be subbed in in both places above.

Answer (score 8):

On OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion), the listed answers all have issues, as noted in the answers and comments.

- Setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include /usr/local/mysql/lib gives warnings from OS X and from brew
- Using `install_name_tool` to hack where the gem binary looks would need to be redone each time the gem is installed or upgraded.
- Switch to `brew`'s mysql may not work; and in any case I don't want to reconfigure an already-working installation

A simpler and robust solution IMHO is to put a link to the library in the default dynamic library search path, which conveniently includes `/usr/local/lib`.  That is:

```
ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

Comment: fantastic, I tried all the above and this one worked immediately

Answer (score 5):

Bill,

Frederic's answer will solve this problem, however you may have to change some of the items in the command depending on versions and how things are named on your system.

For example, on the most recent version of mysql libmysqlclient.16.dylib is actually libmysqlclient.18.dylib.  Try doing a:

```
locate libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

If that does not return the path you can go to:

```
/usr/local/{your-mysql}/lib
```

to find the file. Then just a PWD to find the correct directory for the command.

You will also need to determine what the actual package names of the rubies you have installed are.  You can find this by using

```
rvm info
```

For example, my installation of 1.9.2 is ruby-1.9.2.p180, not ruby-1.9.2p0.  This will need to be changed in Frederics command as well.

So, for me Frederic's command became for fixing the rvm rubies for 1.8.7 and 1.9.2, respectively:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql-5.5.10-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle

sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql-5.5.10-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

Answer (score 3):

below via: http://lightyearsoftware.com/2011/02/mysql-5-5-on-mac-os-x/

**Update July 2012:**

A change in OS X 10.8 makes the easy method above less elegant. If you set that variable, every time you run a setuid or setgid program, you get this warning on stderr:

```
dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (...) is setuid or setgid
```

Ruby developers using Phusion Passenger Standalone will see this message displayed in their console every five seconds. It gets really irritating, very fast.

I have filed a bug with Apple. It’s also at OpenRadar.

In the meantime, there is also a third way to fix the client library path problem that doesn’t require setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH (working around this 10.8 issue) or hacking .bundle files with install_name_tool:

```
$ brew install mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck on this for a while and came to a different solution.

Notice how the missing library is **version 16**:

> Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib (LoadError)

Turns out I had version 20 of that library - `libmysqlclient.20.dylib`

I correctly had `gem 'mysql2'` in my Gemfile, but what I needed to do was uninstall the gem, `gem uninstall mysql` (I had multiple versions of the gem installed) and then doing a new `bundle install` to get *just* the version I needed of this library.

After that it looked for - and found - the correct version of that lib.

Answer (score 1):

Mine was in a different location, I had to use:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle.
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgraded mysql to latest version and reinstall mysql2 gem works to me
`brew upgrade mysql`
`gem uninstall mysql2`
`gem install mysql2`

BTW: My MySQL version is 5.7.18, mysql2 gem version is 0.4.5

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do (similar to others)

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.3.10/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```