# MySQL 5.5.8 with Snow Leopard and mysql2 gem problem

Tags: mysql, mysql2

I have installed MySQL 5.5.8 successfully and mysql2 gem 0.2.6.
but when I execute `rake db:create`
It tell me:

```
dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: Incompatible library version: mysql2.bundle requires version 17.0.0 or later, but libmysqlclient.16.dylib provides version 16.0.0 - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
/Users/vvdpzz/mayday/Rakefile:4
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What should I do?
How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this: 
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle

Answer (score 0):

[rails server fails to start with mysql2 using rvm & ruby 1.9.2-p0 on OSX 10.6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512362/rails-server-fails-to-start-with-mysql2-using-rvm-ruby-1-9-2-p0-on-osx-10-6-5)

Comment: In that discussion they used the install_name_tool to change the path to the library.  That's the part you want to pay attention to.