# Unable to start rails server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I have installed rails and mysql. I have also installed mysql2 gem. I created a rails application by the command
 rails new try_cms -d mysql
 It was created successfully. But when I try to run the WEBrick server using rails server command I get the following errors.

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    from /Users/dilippednekar/Sites/try_cms/config/application.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:28
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean rails version 3.0.3 :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running this (see similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512362/rails-server-fails-to-start-with-mysql2-using-rvm-ruby-1-9-2-p0-on-osx-10-6-5))

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.16.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. I would appreciate if you can explain me what exactly that command is gonna do.

Comment: That command tells the mysql2 bundle to ues the full path of `/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib` instead of just a filename of `libmysqlclient.16.dylib`.

Comment: I tried to do this to fix the problem for myself, but I neglected to update the versions. I.e. on my system, I should have put mysql2-0.3.6.. Now when I try to start rails server, it's looking for 0.2.6. Do you know how I can reverse this problem?  I tried to re-enter your answer with the updated versions but it didn't do anything. Indeed, it didn't even ask me for my root password again

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into this problem myself. Make sure you update the version numbers.

sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle

Answer (score 2):

For some reason the mysql2.bundle file was not in my mysql2 gem.  I ran

```
 gem uninstall mysql2
```

and the gem was uninstalled. Then I immediately ran

```
sudo gem install mysql2
```

Then

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.16.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

Finally `rails s` launched the server!

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems. The solutio  that worked for me was found [here](http://freddyandersen.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/mysql-5-5-snow-leopard-and-rails/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want something a little less intrusive, just set the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable in your MySQL's lib direction.

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MYSQL_HOME/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient15-dev libmysqlclient15off libmysql-ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just hit with this using Rails 3.1.0, ruby-1.9.2-p290 and mysql2 0.3.7.  My solution was to downgrade to mysql 2.8.1.  Everything looks good so far (I wasn't even able to start the environment).