# Ruby On Rails 3 and Webrick issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, webrick

Thanks for taking a look at this.

I started a beginner's tutorial on RoR through lynda.com. I followed the instructions to the letter. Everything was working so far until I got to accessing Webrick. When I typed in "rails server" to begin work, I got this error message below.

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle

from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2.rb:8
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
from /Users/macuser/Sites/simplecms/config/application.rb:7
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:28
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6
```

I'm using a

- iMac
- Ruby 1.87
- Gem 1.7.2

Since I'm not experienced with anything Ruby, I'm lost on how to fix this.

Thanks in advance for your attention and help if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Run these at the terminal:

```
gem install bundler
bundle
```

And then you should be able to boot the server.

**Edit**: You should really look into using [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) to manage your ruby installs and gemsets. It'll save you a lot of time and effort in installing them too.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem as you (also attempting to go through the Lynda course), and also being a newbie I got pretty frustrated pretty quickly.

Buuuuut, after some searching, I found and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859505/unable-to-start-rails-server) I got it to work.

First, I installed the 32-bit version of MySQL, as opposed to the 64-bit version, but I'm not sure if that made a difference.

Then, uninstall the Mysql gem

```
 gem uninstall mysql2
```

then reinstall it

```
sudo gem install mysql2
```

and finally

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

and you should be good to go! Worked for me anyways. good luck!

Comment: you should use rvm and not play around with sudo but
`install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib $GEM_HOME/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle` did the trick for me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/
```

This is the code that worked for me :D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I simply ran the following code:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib
```

Press enter, and then run

```
rails server
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

**Correct way that worked for me was:**

**cd ~** [command]

**nano .bash_profile** [command]

*add this line of code:*

> **export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"**

**ctrl+x** [save]

**y** [yes]

**cd Sites/sitename/** [command]

**rails server** [run WEBrick server]

and you should get this message:

> => Booting WEBrick
>   => Rails 3.2.11 application starting in development on **localhost:3000**
>   => Call with -d to detach