# Webrick server error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby On Rails 3 and Webrick issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690200/ruby-on-rails-3-and-webrick-issue)

```
$ rails server
/Users/Vineeth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:1:in `require': dlopen(/Users/Vineeth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25
/lib/ruby_debug.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _ruby_current_thread (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/Vineeth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/Vineeth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.bundle - /Users/Vineeth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.bu
ndle
        from /Users/Vineeth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/Vineeth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug.rb:5:in `require'
        from /Users/Vineeth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Vineethsfrom /Users/Vineeth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
        from /Users/Vineeth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /Users/Vineeth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
        from /Users/Vineeth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
        from /Users/Vineeth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
        from /Users/Vineeth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
        from /Users/Vineeth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
        from /Users/Vineeth/QA4/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/Vineeth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
        from /Users/Vineeth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /Users/Vineeth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from /Users/Vineeth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

When i tried to start server from Aptana studio it shows like above........
please help me solve this error......thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your debugger to

```
gem 'debugger'
```

in your Gemfile.

Remove

```
gem 'ruby-debug19'
```

don't forget to run `bundle install` again.