# How to make a Rails application using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

To make a Rails application with MySQL, I do the following:

```
rails new application -database=mysql
```

That doesn't work though, instead it gives my SQLite.
I don't want SQLite, I want MySQL.

How can I solve this?

Comment: are you installed mysql?

Comment: maybe you need more than that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366934/help-setting-up-ruby-on-rails-and-mysql-reward-offered

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking at the command to create new rails app with mysql configuration in database.yml

```
rails new app --database mysql
```

I hope it answers your query.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to install mysql2 in your system

```
sudo  gem install mysql2 -v=0.2.11
```

Once you have installed mysql2, then you are ready to create a new app with Mysql as default

```
rails new sample_app -d mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use bundler, then you should add

```
gem "mysql2"
```

to your Gemfile and run

```
bundle install
```

and then specify your database settings in config/database.yml