# ruby 1.9.3 db:migrate issues

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

So I am trying to migrate a database I created and I keep getting this string of errors. Not sure what to do! Thanks

```
Camerons-MacBook-Air:depot Cameron$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
dlopen(/Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
/Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `require'
/Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
/Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
/Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
/Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
/Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
/Users/Cameron/depot/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Cameron/depot/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/Users/Cameron/depot/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5509692/1879699). I guess you are having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and this line of code

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`

worked for me.

You can find further information in this link from the original source: [mysql2 library not loaded](http://blog.tejasparikh.com/2013/04/how-to-fix-library-not-loaded.html)