# Why do I get a "Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have been following a video tutorial and the database is created, but when trying to follow the step by going to directory and entering `rake: dbmigrate`
 I get an error.

```
Ians-MacBook-Pro:music_library iansherwood$ rake db migrate
rake aborted!
dlopen(/Users/iansherwood/Sites/music_library/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/iansherwood/Sites/music_library/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/iansherwood/Sites/music_library/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
/Users/iansherwood/Sites/music_library/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require'
/Users/iansherwood/Sites/music_library/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
/Users/iansherwood/Sites/music_library/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/iansherwood/Sites/music_library/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: There are a couple other similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512362/rails-server-fails-to-start-with-mysql2-using-rvm-ruby-1-9-2-p0-on-osx-10-6-5 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serv that might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax should be: `rake db:migrate`, and not `rake: dbmigrate` or `rake db migrate`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `bundle exec rake db:migrate`?

Another possibility is that you don't have my MySQL running.
The easiest way to check for that would be:

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

If it isn't running and you installed MySQL through 
homebrew (common video guide way to install it) then you can run `mysql.server start`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your colon use might be inconsistent.  Remember to use:

```
rake db:migrate
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you include "gem 'mysql2'" in your Gemfile?